# Firebase: Problem getting data from nested onSnapshot

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have the following useEffect set up to fetch some data from firebase to populate a flatlist

```
useEffect(() => {
  return db
    .collection('accounts')
    .doc(currentAccountId)
    .collection('shops')
    .doc(currentShopId)
    .collection('sensors')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const list = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        
        const { sensorReadingsId } = doc.data();

        // This works, but doesn't load the additional data I need.
        // list.push({ ...{ id: doc.id }, ...doc.data() });

        // This doesn't seem to load anything.
        db.collection('sensors')
          .doc(sensorReadingsId.toString())
          .onSnapshot((documentSnapshot) => {
            list.push({ ...{ id: doc.id }, ...doc.data(), ...documentSnapshot.data() });
          });

      });

      setSensorsData(list);
      console.log(sensorsData);
      setLoading(false);

    });
}, [currentAccountId, currentShopId]);
```

Here's the problem: my flatlist doesn't load anything. When I initially load the screen, that console.log outputs an empty array. If I force it to re-render by saving the screen file, the array is correctly populated.

As noted in that comment, if I just use `list.push({ ...{ id: doc.id }, ...doc.data() });` instead of `db.collection('sensors')...` it loads the sensors fine, but without the additional data that I need.

How do I resolve this? Thanks in advance!

---

**Solution:** As @Rajitha Udayanga has pointed out, checking the length of the first querysnapshot against the list array is a great way to check whether or not all the data has been loaded. Here's the working code (note the conditional that `setSensorsData` has been moved into):

```
useEffect(() => {
  return db
    .collection('accounts')
    .doc(currentAccountId)
    .collection('shops')
    .doc(currentShopId)
    .collection('sensors')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const list = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        
        const { sensorReadingsId } = doc.data();

        db.collection('sensors')
          .doc(sensorReadingsId.toString())
          .onSnapshot((documentSnapshot) => {
            list.push({ ...{ id: doc.id }, ...doc.data(), ...documentSnapshot.data() });
            
            // Fix is here:
            if (querySnapshot.docs.length === list.length) {
              setSensorsData(list);
              console.log(sensorsData);
              setLoading(false);
            }

          });

      });

    });
}, [currentAccountId, currentShopId]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  return db
    .collection('accounts')
    .doc(currentAccountId)
    .collection('shops')
    .doc(currentShopId)
    .collection('sensors')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const list = [];

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    
    const { sensorReadingsId } = doc.data();

    db.collection('sensors')
      .doc(sensorReadingsId.toString())
      .onSnapshot((documentSnapshot) => {
     
        const newData = { 
           ...{ id: doc.id }, 
           ...doc.data(), 
           ...documentSnapshot.data() 
        };

        const itemIndex = list.findIndex(item => item.id === 
              newData.id);

        if (itemIndex !== -1) {
              list[itemIndex] = newData;
        } else {
              list.push(newData);
        }

        // do it like thi
        if (querySnapshot.docs.length === list.length) {
           setSensorsData(list);
           console.log(sensorsData);
           setLoading(false);
        }
      });

  });

});
}, [currentAccountId, currentShopId]);
```

Comment: If sensors data already added to your `list` array you can update the existing object and otherwise, you can add new data.

Comment: Now you are assuming that the inner callbacks will fire in the correct order, which is highly unlikely.

Comment: Yes, that's right. but I think this will works. the order does not matter.

Comment: This is great, it works with some slight modifications: there's a bit of extra complexity in there that isn't needed. See my addition to my question

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I have zero experience with React.

In Angular I deal with such issues using RxJS's combineLatest.

However, you can try this one:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return db
    .collection('accounts')
    .doc(currentAccountId)
    .collection('shops')
    .doc(currentShopId)
    .collection('sensors')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const list = [];
      const useValues = () => {
        if (list.some(value => value === undefined)) {
          return; // not everything has loaded yet - abort
        }
        setSensorsData(list);
        console.log(sensorsData);
        setLoading(false);
      }
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc, index) => {
        list.push(undefined);
        const { sensorReadingsId } = doc.data();
        db.collection('sensors')
          .doc(sensorReadingsId.toString())
          .onSnapshot((documentSnapshot) => {
            list[index] = ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data(), ...documentSnapshot.data() });
            useValues();
          });
      });
    });
}, [currentAccountId, currentShopId]);
```

And don't forget to [detach the listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) when you don't need them anymore.